# What is wrong in this proof that $\pi=2$ or $x=2$?

Tags: fake-proofs

Let us consider the number $$\Large\pi^{\pi^\pi}=\pi^{\pi\cdot\pi}=\pi^{\pi^2}$$

As the bases are equal, the exponents must be equal, So $$\pi=2$$

You can take any $x$ instead of $\pi$.

What is wrong in this proof?

Comment: What is the argument why that should somehow indicate that $\pi = 2$?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Maybe you are mixing up $2\pi$ and $\pi^{2}$ here,

Comment: The first equality is false.  $x^{x^x}\neq x^{x\cdot x}$

Comment: @callus Why? It was taught to us in school in 7th class that $a^{b^c}=a^{b\cdot c}$

Comment: @Kartik No (hopefully). What was taught was most likely $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^{(b\cdot c)}$. In general, $a^{(b^c)} \neq \left(a^b\right)^c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So we can change the question to $(\pi^\pi)^\pi$

Comment: So we have $\left(\pi^\pi\right)^\pi = \pi^{(\pi\cdot\pi)} = \pi^{\left(\pi^2\right)}$. All correct so far. Nothing to suggest $\pi=2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why? Still we can say that the bases are equal, so exponents will be equal

Comment: @Kartik That the exponents are equal just says $\pi \cdot \pi = \pi^2$.

Comment: Oh, you just changed it. Now the first equation is wrong, $a^{b^c} = a^{\left(b^c\right)} \neq \left(a^b\right)^c = a^{b\cdot c}$.

Comment: I just changed it because ${\pi^\pi}^\pi$ looked like $\pi^{\pi\pi}$ It does not change the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Kartik It changes the meaning of the expressions in the chain of equations. $\pi^{\pi^\pi} = \pi^{\left(\pi^\pi\right)}$ is different from $\left(\pi^{\pi}\right)^\pi = \pi^{\pi\pi}$.

Comment: I meant to say that I only changed it because the typesetting was not correct, I did not change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets write $a \uparrow b$ to mean $a^b$.

Then the following reasoning is correct: $$(\pi \uparrow \pi)\uparrow \pi = \pi \uparrow (\pi \cdot \pi) = \pi \uparrow (\pi \uparrow 2)$$

However, we cannot necessarily deduce that the RHS equals

$$(\pi \uparrow \pi) \uparrow 2$$

because [exponentiation isn't associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Non-associativity). Indeed, Google calculator tells me that:

- $\pi \uparrow (\pi \uparrow 2) \approx 80662.6659386$
- $(\pi \uparrow \pi) \uparrow 2 \approx 1329.48908322$

so if the calculator is correct to even the first decimal place, then

$$(\pi \uparrow \pi) \uparrow 2 \neq \pi \uparrow (\pi \uparrow 2).$$

Moral of the story: if in doubt, find better notation!

Answer (score 8):

I think you are mixing up
$$
\left(\pi^\pi\right)^\pi=\pi^{\pi^2}
$$
with 
$$
\pi^{\left(\pi^\pi\right)}\neq \pi^{\pi^2}.
$$

In general,
$$
\left(a^b\right)^c\neq a^{\left(b^c\right)}
$$
but if $a=b=c=2$ it is true since then $b\times c=b^c$.

Comment: You might add that unadorned $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ by notational convention.

Answer (score 5):

If you can take any $x$ instead of $\pi$, why didn't you take $3$ or $10$ instead of $\pi$?$$10^{10^{10}}=10^{10000000000}$$
$$10^{10\cdot10}=10^{100}\ne10^{10000000000}$$